# Invalidate Resolution for Custom Store

Tags: reactjs, wordpress-gutenberg, gutenberg-blocks

I'm trying to clear a store for a Gutenberg block with an interval to force a fetch to the API every 15 seconds.

This is how I get the data:

```js
const data = useSelect(
    (select) => select( CUSTOM_STORE ).getMyData(id),
    [id]
);
```

Using an `setInterval` to invalidate my `CUSTOM_STORE` like so

```js
useEffect(() => {
    
    setInterval(() => {         
        invalidateResolutionForStoreSelector( CUSTOM_STORE );           
    }, 15000);

}, []);
```

now this works, but it clears the whole `CUSTOM_STORE` (obviously)

How can is just invalidate the data with the given `id`?

Doing it with `invalidateResolutionForStoreSelector( CUSTOM_STORE, id )` doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

In your scenario as described, I'd try implementing your `CUSTOM_STORE` outside of `@wordpress/data` like the `customStore()` [example in the documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/packages/packages-data/#generic-stores). Then you can use `subscribe()` (like Redux subscribe) to listen for state changes rather than attempting to invalidate the store every 15s.

Alternatively, you could try:
`wp.data.dispatch('core').invalidateResolution(CUSTOM_STORE, [id]);` if invalidating is the way you wish to go..

Comment: That's what I actually do (or try to do) [Here's](https://github.com/everpress-co/mailster-block-forms/tree/develop/blocks/forms/store) is custom store from a different project so you see what I mean.

The problem with `invalidateResolution` is that it clears the data for all stored ids.

Comment: Also the change happens on the server and involves an API request (which I like to limit to only when needed)